# React Native AsyncStorage unable to see updated data from javascript when stored from native code

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I am persisting values to Async Storage from my objective C code like this:

```
  dispatch_async(self.storage.methodQueue, ^{
    if ([self.storage respondsToSelector:@selector(multiSet:callback:)]) {      
      [self.storage performSelector:@selector(multiSet:callback:) withObject:@[@[@"MYKEY", @"MYVALUE"]] withObject:[^(NSArray* response) {
        NSLog(@"Contents: %@",response);
      } copy]];
    }else{
      NSLog(@"storage does not respond!!!");
    }
  });
```

This actually works really well, except that the front end can't seem to see these values until I close and restart the app.

When I try to read the value from the front end with:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('MYKEY', function(err, result) { ... });
```

I always get the value that was there before the app was started up.

I know that my use-case isn't terribly standard, but this seems like a reasonable thing to try to do. Any thoughts on how I might be able to read a value that is persisted from native code, without having to restart the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem without ever entirely understanding what the underlying cause was. If somebody is able to find an explanation, please please share.

My thoughts were that generally I'd probably want to access the same storage object instead of using one in Objective C and one in javascript. So what I did was create a `NativeBridge.m` file with these contents:

```
#import "NativeBridge.h"
#import "StorageManager.h"

@implementation NativeBridge

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getMeasurements:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {

  RCTAsyncLocalStorage* storage = [[StorageManager sharedManager] storage];

  dispatch_async(storage.methodQueue, ^{
    if ([storage respondsToSelector:@selector(multiGet:callback:)]) {
      [storage performSelector:@selector(multiGet:callback:) withObject:@[@"measurements"] withObject:[^(NSArray* response) {
        callback(@[response[1][0][1]]);
      } copy]];
    }else{
      NSLog(@"storage does not respond!!!");
    }
  });
}

@end
```

and the corresponding header file:

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTAsyncLocalStorage.h>

@interface NativeBridge : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

That way I could make the call via my own exported method directly from the javascript:

```
import { NativeBridge } from 'NativeModules';

NativeBridge.getMeasurements(response => { ... });
```

## Additional implementation info

A pattern that I used (that may not necessarily be required) was to use the standard singleton pattern in the native code to house the RCTAsyncLocalStorage object.

There is a ton of information out there about how to do that, but I thought I'd mention it in case it's useful to anybody.